# Redirect to Angular 6 Route from other application

Tags: web, angular-ui-router, angular6

I am working on angular 6 .. I want to make the user redirects to specific route from outer link .. but when the user clicks the link he got redirected to "index"

and this is my routes

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "Startup", component: StartupComponent },
      { path: "Login", component: SigninComponent },
      { path: "FirstPage", component: FirstPageComponent },
      { path: "Index", component: IndexComponent, canActivate: [ComponentGuardService] },
      { path: "Requests", component: IndexComponent, canActivate: [ComponentGuardService] },
      { path: "RequestsDetails/:id", component: RequestsDetailsComponent, canActivate: [ComponentGuardService] },
      { path: "RequestsStatistics", component: RequestsStatisticsComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuardService,ComponentGuardService] },

      { path: "", redirectTo: "Index", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "**", redirectTo: "Login", pathMatch: "full" }
    ], { useHash: true })
```

and ComponentGuardService

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    let me = Shared.Me;
    if (me == null || me.Id == "") {
      this.navigator.navigate(["/Startup"]);
      return false;
    }
    else
      return true;
  }
```

I want to make the user redirect to **Requests** route

thank you :)

Comment: It tries to go to Requests route or it go directly to index?

Comment: I think it tries to go to Requests route first .. but I am not sure

Comment: is canActive executed? this route is ok navigating into angular site?

Comment: yes its OK and nothing wrong with it .. and I cant navigate to any route by copy-paste the url .. it always redirecting to index

Comment: make ax external link is possible, try to enable route tracing to see what is happening and let me know please

Comment: Please post the URL that you want redirect.

Comment: the trace shows that the routing going directly to "/Startup" not to "/Requests" .. the "/Startup" is the home page